# How can I get Emacs in Windows to interactively communicate with Python matplotlib?

Tags: python, eglot

I am using Anaconda Python on Windows 11 and WSL2.

In VS Code (Windows) and Emacs/Eglot (WSL2), the following code runs fine when I run it interactively:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(matplotlib.get_backend()) # -> is always QtAgg
plt.ion()

plt.clf()
plt.plot([1,2,3])

plt.clf()
plt.plot([4,5,6])
```

However, the Python interpreter always hangs on the the first plotting command (or after closing the first plot) when using Emacs/Eglot in Windows 11.

The backend is always QtAgg in every case.

What's different in the way Emacs/Eglot in Windows 11 is communicating with the Python interpreter (and how do I fix it)?